# CloudObject when defining functions - how to remove?

Tags: function-construction, wolfram-cloud

I'm an absolute idiot when it comes to Mathematica - I only use it for really basic things (because we use it as a graphic calculator in my high school class), so formatting will be less than ideal. Apologies in advance.

Recently when I've tried to define a function with the syntax:

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

and then I type:

```
?f
```

The output says:

```
CloudObject`Private`f
f[x_]:=x^2
```

This is happening for every function I define. Moreover, usually the function name turns black after it is defined, but that doesn't happen anymore - it just stays blue, which might be related to the whole CloudObject issue? What even is CloudObject?? And more importantly, how do I get rid of it? I just want it to go back to what it was before.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a package was interrupted while loading, leaving your context in a bad state. Here is a simulation of what you're observing:

```
Begin["CloudObject`Private`"];
f[x_] := x^2
```

Then:

```
?f
```

> CloudObject`Private`f
>
> f[x_]:=x^2

Notice the bad context:

```
$Context
```

> "CloudObject`Private`"

So, the remedy is to return to the `` Global` `` context:

```
End[];
```

Now, the context is good:

```
$Context
```

> "Global`"

Comment: Thanks so much Carl - I think it worked! However, I seem to have a new problem - the '?' no longer works for built-in functions. Usually when I type in the input: ?Plot it will give me a list of the possible ways to use the Plot function. However now it says:
System`Plot

Attributes[Plot]={HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected}

 Options[Plot]={AlignmentPoint->Center,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio,Axes->True,AxesLabel->None,AxesOrigin->Automatic,AxesStyle->{},Background->None,BaselinePosition->Automatic,BaseStyle->{},ClippingStyle->None,ColorFunction->Automatic

etc. How do I change this?

Comment: @Ashley Your $ContextPath has also been corrupted. You could try ``$ContextPath = {"System`", "Global`"}``, but it might be easier to just quit the kernel and restart.